# Method.Invoke() behaving strangely C# .NET BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, invoke

I have the following code with some detail taken out:

```
private void bkgdProcessData_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bkgdProcessData.ReportProgress(0);

    bool rdPickChecked = false;
    bool rdAutoChecked = true;
    int lbLengthsSelectedIndex = 0;
    string lbLengthsText = "";

    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
        rdPickChecked = rdPick.Checked;
        rdAutoChecked = rdAuto.Checked;
        lbLengthsSelectedIndex = lbLengths.SelectedIndex;
        lbLengthsText = lbLengths.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }));

    if (rdPickChecked == true && e.Cancel == false)
    {
        if (lbLengthsSelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (SortedOrderedPieces[0].PieceLength > double.Parse(lbLengthsText))
        {
            ...
        }
        else
            ...
    }
    else if (rdAutoChecked == true && e.Cancel == false)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, this whole procedure is the BackgroundWorker. I am using `MethodInvoke()` to access UI elements and write them to variables in this procedure.

My problem is, when I put a breakpoint at the beginning of this procedure and step through it, it sets the variables correctly and the program works fine, **but** if I remove the breakpoint and just run it, the variables don't set and my program doesn't work. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `BeginInvoke`, which is asynchronous - it will execute the given delegate in the UI thread, but *not* block the currently executing thread... which means it's *highly likely* that you'll end up using the variables in the rest of your method before the delegate has executed.

One solution is just to use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`.

Another option is to pick up the values from the UI *before* starting the `BackgroundWorker`, so that you don't need to go back to the UI thread. Exactly how you'd do that will depend on how and where you're launching the background worker.

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed the problem! One other thing: Would you recommend using one `MethodInvoker` and then calling it for each `Invoke` or would you create a new `MethodInvoker` each time like I have done?

Comment: @gnarlybracket: It's not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. What you've got is fine though.